# Approach to development environments

Tags: testing, environment

I was wondering how companies organize their development environments. More specifically I am interested to know:

Does each developer has a complete deployment environment including application servers and database in their desktop? In the case of a shared Database how do you ensure DB unit testing does not interfere across developers?

Sharing your experiences and thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, developers do typically run an app server locally (necessary because they need to deploy their current code to it), but seldom a database.

You can have separate DB schemas for each developer on the central server to isolate them if necessary, but actual unit tests should never hit the real database. That would be integration tests, and those are more typically run on an integration or build server rather than by individual developers.